# AJAX request authentication to PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, pdo, authentication

Recently I started looking at my AJAX call security and found some code that uses tokens, request and referer in an attempt to authenticate the call and stop XSS and CSRF.

The AJAX calls are for the article list / article table in the admin section.

Note: The PHP will not run unless you are logged in — it uses a cookie and sessions to authenticate user.

**EDIT:** Implemented schisms function name suggestion.

The following code works as it should but is it a good method?

**Create our Token:**

```
$token = md5(rand(1000,9999)); 
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

**The button to deactivate / activate an article:**

```
<td>
if($article_active === 1){ 
echo '<input type="button" class="active_button" title="Deactivate" value="YES" name="'.$article_id.'"/>'; 
} 
else { 
echo '<input type="button" class="active_button" title="Activate" value="NO" name="'.$article_id.'" />'; 
}
echo '
</td>
```

**The AJAX call:**

```
// ACTIVATE / DEACTIVATE WITH LINK
$(document).on("click",".active_button",function() {

    var form_data = {
        articleID: $(this).attr("name"),
        active: $(this).val(),
        selector: $("#selector").attr("name"),
        data: $("#data").val(),
        token:'<?php echo $token; ?>', 
        is_ajax: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controllers/articlecontrol.php",
    data: form_data,
    success: function(data){
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
    });
});
```

**The PHP that validates the AJAX request and sends the data to a PHP function:**

```
// ACTIVATE / DEACTIVATE w/BUTTON
if(isset($_POST['active']) && $selector === 'article') {

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' && isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['token']){

                $articleid = $_POST['articleID'];
                $active = ($_POST['active'] === 'YES') ? 0 : 1;
                $backend->setArticleStatus($articleid, $active);
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['status'] = '<div class="error">There was a Problem Activating / Deactivating that Article</div>';
            }
}
```

**The PHP activate / deactivate function (part of a class):**

```
/**
 * Activate / Deactivate Article w/Button
 */

 public function setArticleStatus($articleid, $active) {
    $query = 'UPDATE wcx_articles SET article_active = :active WHERE article_id = :articleid';
    $stmt = $this->queryIt($query);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':active', $active);
    $stmt = $this->bind(':articleid', $articleid);
    if($this->execute()) {
        if ($active === 0) {
            $_SESSION['status'] = '<div class="success">Article Deactivated Successfully</div>';
        } 
        else {
            $_SESSION['status'] = '<div class="success">Article Activated Successfully</div>';
        }
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['status'] = '<div class="error">There was a Problem Activating / Deactivating that Article</div>';
    }
 }
```

Comment: @AlexL Any thoughts?

Comment: @AlexGarrett any ideas?

Comment: A new '$token' is generated every 'AJAX' call

Comment: After testing `XSS` attacks it seems that `$token` stops them just fine. I am using `$bits = 32;
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bits));` for the token now, so its truly random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Prefer `mt_rand()` to `rand()`.
- Just a comment: your usage of tokens is similar to using [nonces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). There are established nonce generation libraries for PHP, and I suggest you take a look into them.
- `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is in general not a 100% reliable way to detect AJAX-ness. However, jQuery sends this header with its AJAX calls, so you should be okay. I'd suggest getting rid of the `is_ajax` in your request data though.
- Your input element is at best confusing, and at worst messy. Why is *Deactivate* paired with *YES*, and *Activate* with *NO*? I'd prefer just using *deactivate* and *activate* as the button values, and templating inline:

  ```
  <td><input type="button" class="active_button" name="<?= $article_id ?>" value="<?= $article_active ? "de" : "" ?>activate" /></td>
  ```
- `activateDeactivate` isn't a very good name. Maybe `setActiveStatus` or something?

Comment: So, apart from the obvious crappy code you pointed out, the AJAX authentication should stop XSS and CSRF? I just need the code to know the call came from the same domain and a valid trusted user

Comment: Title is deactivate, so if active is YES then the title on hover would be deactivate.